# Node MongoDB records not available after callback with writeconcern

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

We're seeing this puzzling problem on our production server where MongoDB occasionally isn't able to query records for which a *writeConcern* just told us that the records were written to the database.

The following versions are installed on the server:

- Node.js 4.x LTS
- MongoDB 3.2
- node-mongodb-native 2.2

After initiating a `bulk` action with *writeConcern 1*, the records are immediately queried in the callback, for reasons.

On our development servers, this works as expected 100% of the time. However, on our production server with about 10,000 queries per day, we observe this second query returning zero documents in about 0.01% of cases.

Interestingly, *there are* in fact documents that should be returned, and the documents *do* get returned when the exact same query is fired 500 milliseconds later. Obviously though, we do not want to add a latency of 500 milliseconds to all our responses just

Here is a simplified illustration of what I explained above:

```
let bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()

// bulk gathering data
// ...

bulk.execute({w: 1}, function(error, result) {
    console.log(`Inserted ${result.nInserted} records`)

    return mongo.collection(colName).aggregate([{
        // Some query
    }])
    .toArray()
    .then(function(rows) {
        // 99.9% of the time, rows are here.
        // 0.1% of time, rows is erroneously an empty array.
    })
}
```

Considering that writeConcern is meant specifically for cases like this, **what causes this to fail in a small amount of cases?**

Note that there is a single mongodb instance running. No clusters or shards.

Comment: *...  on our production server  ...*. So what is different there? Odds are that you are using some different connection settings in production, and likely something related to `READ_PREFERENCE` where you are probably reading from a secondary node and not the primary. Note that `{ w: 1 }` **only** acknowledges the write to the **Primary** node, and does not guarantee that the data is **always** written to the "secondary" node. I know you say *"no clusters"*, but the effect you describe would seem to indicate there is indeed a replica-set configuration and such a read preference is set.

Comment: Also `{ w: 1 }` is actually the **default** of all drivers anyway. So the code explicitly using it is not actually doing anything the driver simply does already anyway. In this context it's a useless setting unless for some reason you set the **connection** to default to `{ w: 0 }`. Also not sure why you are mixing callback's and promises here, it won't be related to the problem stated but from a coding clarity standpoint it's never a good idea. Better to pick one approach and stick to it.